# iPhone Call Log/History Access - Existing Appstore App has access...But how?

Tags: iphone, logging, history, calllog

I am trying to incorporate in my app the ability to count incoming/outgoing voice minutes.

I though this was impossible, especially with getting approved in the App Store.

However, I noticed that this recently uploaded app in the App Store has done exactly it... Doe anyone have any idea how? I this that this is definitely not on the carrier side..

App name: "Navita T.E.M Personal

Link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navita-t.e.m.-personal/id590228620?mt=8

I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: What makes you so sure it's not getting this from the carrier?

Comment: Because I have tested with several carriers from around the world. It is extremely unlikely that this company from Brazil has agreements with every carrier around the world.

Comment: Is this the solution?
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604

Comment: No, there's nothing in that class that would do what you're looking for.

Comment: Can anyone help please :)?

Comment: Does anyone know of a site that I can pay a developer to solve this specific task?

Comment: "What makes you so sure it's not getting this from the carrier?" +1 to newb1188's reply. How would a tiny Brazilan company have that sort of intimate relationship with major US carriers. It just wouldn't. Also if the app is terminated (as opposed to backgrounded or suspended)when the call is placed then it does not appear in the history, IF the app was able to get the information from the carrier it would be able to get info for missed calls when it isn't running by contacting the carrier server retrospectively. Therefore this app is not getting the info from the carrier.